# Adding spaces before and after a number (Regex)

Tags: python, regex

I'm stuck and that's why I'm asking you for help.
I need to add a space in the string before and after the number if there 
is no number before it and no number after it and there is no space before and after.
 
This is best seen in the example.

**String**: *Adam20 Margaret30Tom 20 test*
**Expected result**: *Adam 20 Margaret 30 Tom 20 test*

I found this partial solution but I can't modify it, regex is my weak point.

```
import re
line = "Adam20 Margaret30Tom 20 test"
x=re.sub(r'(?<=[0-9])(?=[^\s])', r' ', line)
print(x)
>> Adam2 0 Margaret3 0 Tom 2 0 test*<br/>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your lookaround attempt can be expanded to `(?<=[^\d ])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[^\d ])` and replace with space. [See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/q1uCgD/1). Advantage is, that it would not add space at start or end of the string but it's probably less efficient than @kaya3's answer with capture group and you could use `strip()` after doing the replacement if starting/ending with digit :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a capturing group, and refer to it in the substitution:

```py
>>> line = "Adam20 Margaret30Tom 20 test"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r' ?(\d+) ?', r' \1 ', line)
'Adam 20 Margaret 30 Tom 20 test'
```

Explanation: The `?` matches 0 or 1 spaces, `(\d+)` matches 1 or more digits and captures them to group 1, and `\1` uses the contents of the match for group 1 in the replacement.